# How to execute a script from CPP process which will kill that process also

Tags: c++, linux, websocket

I have a restart script which will kill and start the exe.
Now I need to call that restart script from the same CPP based process.
Tried to call it like:

```
{

    std::stringstream restartScript;
    restartScript << "nohup sh -c /TEST/restart.sh " << "&") ;
    std::system(restartScript.str().c_str());

}
```

Also tried:

```
{

    std::stringstream restartScript;
    restartScript << "bash -c /TEST/restart.sh " << "& disown";
    std::system(restartScript.str().c_str());

}
```

Using above options though process is getting killed; it seems some zombie thread is holding the Websocket resource allocated and hence getting below exception while starting the exe again from the script called from that process.
"asio listen error: system:98 (Address already in use)"
[exe is using websocketpp library and already set_reuse_addr is true).

restart.sh has following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 `pidof processA`
sleep 2
/TEST/bin/processA
```

Websocket Listening code:

```
void WebSocketServer::run()
{
    // Listen on port 9090
    m_endpoint.set_reuse_addr(true);
    m_endpoint.listen(9090);
    m_endpoint.start_accept();

    // Start the Asio io_service run loop
    m_endpoint.run();
    std::cout << "WS Server listening on " << std::endl;
}
```

Exception:

```
[info] asio listen error: system:98 (Address already in use)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'websocketpp::exception'
  what():  Underlying Transport Error
```

Please help out with a solution to : " execute the restart script from cpp process which will restart the process from which it is called)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of `/TEST/restart.sh`, as well as the part of your code that tries to start listening.

Comment: updated with the requested info, please have a look

Comment: Does your process spawn any child processes? When you get the error, can you use `netstat` or `ss` to check the status of the port?

Comment: No child process is spawn from processA . And yes i could see that port is still in use even after restart script called from processA. Note : If i call the restart script directly from terminal , process is getting restarted properly

Comment: Though I could see that port is occupied , not seeing process running as the entry is missing in output of "ps -ef"

Answer (score 1):

By default, file descriptors (including listening sockets) are inherited by child processes and persisted across `exec`. This means that when your program attempts to restart itself, the old socket is still listening, since the new process is the old process's descendant, so it fails when it tries to listen on a new one. There's two ways you can fix this:

1. Move restart logic to a parent process of the process that does the listening, instead of within the same process
2. Call `m_endpoint.stop_listening()` before running the restart script

Comment: The process under consideration is kind of parent process , So Solution #1 doesnot seems to apt for my scenario. Tried Solution#2 , but still getting same address used exception. Note as per the "ss" output :                                                                                                   tcp     CLOSE-WAIT            1                 0               [::1]:9090          [::1]:52166[

Comment: @CryptoDude Your process isn't PID 1, so it can have a parent even if it is a kind of parent itself. And what about #2?

Comment: updated comment. Since this has to run on a different device and to be inline with the existing design/architecture , creating this process under a parent is not a solution i can look at this time .Solution #2 looks cool, BUT not sure why it is not working for my case